# Не меняя DataFrame по заданному условию произвести операцию со строками столбца

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Имеется следующий DataFrame:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо по условию: если в столбце "Усреднённая скорость" значение < 0, то значение в этой строке в столбце "Масштабный коэффициент" умножить на -1.

У меня получается сделать только с выделением столбца по условию:

```
df = df[df['Усреднённая скорость'] < 0]["Масштабный коэффициент"] * -1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как не "ломая" первоначальный DataFrame умножить значения по заданному условию?

Ссылка [на данные .csv](https://yadi.sk/d/hbq7IAmu6wtWxg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.loc[]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['Усреднённая скорость'] < 0, "Масштабный коэффициент"] *= -1
```

---

Демонстрация правильной работы решения для [приведенного примера данных](https://yadi.sk/d/hbq7IAmu6wtWxg):

```
In [69]: df = pd.read_csv("Scale_factor_SensorID_16495_ser.№5.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", header=None)

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
        0      1           2         3         4
0       1   left   -0.998874  1.001128 -0.001345
1       1   left   -0.998646  1.001356  0.003246
2     120   left -119.810929  1.001578  0.002425
3     120   left -119.810709  1.001580  0.001975
4     120   left -119.810087  1.001585  0.001092
...   ...    ...         ...       ...       ...
7539    1  right    0.991193  1.008885 -0.002161
7540    1  right    0.991037  1.009044 -0.000399
7541    1  right    0.990894  1.009190 -0.003662
7542    1  right    0.990769  1.009317  0.001469
7543    1  right    0.990263  1.009833 -0.003643

[7544 rows x 5 columns]

In [71]: df.loc[df[2] < 0, 3] *= -1

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
        0      1           2         3         4
0       1   left   -0.998874 -1.001128 -0.001345
1       1   left   -0.998646 -1.001356  0.003246
2     120   left -119.810929 -1.001578  0.002425
3     120   left -119.810709 -1.001580  0.001975
4     120   left -119.810087 -1.001585  0.001092
...   ...    ...         ...       ...       ...
7539    1  right    0.991193  1.008885 -0.002161
7540    1  right    0.991037  1.009044 -0.000399
7541    1  right    0.990894  1.009190 -0.003662
7542    1  right    0.990769  1.009317  0.001469
7543    1  right    0.990263  1.009833 -0.003643

[7544 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Выводит результат -1. Что-то не так

Comment: @leach, Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__)

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/hbq7IAmu6wtWxg загрузил данные

Comment: @leach Вы случайно не написали у себя в коде когда копировали `= -1` вместо `*= -1`? )

Comment: спасибо. Всё работает, это была моя ошибка. Я прировнял df к выражению, которое Вы написали изначально (df = df.loc[df['Усреднённая скорость'] < 0, "Масштабный коэффициент"] *= -1) из-за чего у меня была ошибка "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Я подумал, что это опечатка и убрал знак * перед равно.

Comment: @CrazyElf именно)